# Inequality problems

Tags: inequality

I have Maths test tomorrow and was just doing my revision when I came across these two questions. Would anyone please give me a nudge in the right direction?

$1)$ If $x$ is real and $$y=\frac{x^2+4x-17}{2(x-3)},$$ show that $|y-5|\geq2$

$2)$ If $a>0$, $b>0$, prove that $$\left(a+\frac1b\right)\left(2b+\frac1{2a}\right)\ge\frac92$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem:
Write it as 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(y-5\right)^2-4&=&\left(\frac{x^2+4x-17}{2(x-3)}-5\right)^2-4\\
&=&\left(\frac{x^2+4x-17-10x+30}{2(x-3)}\right)^2-4\\
&=&\left(\frac{x^2-6x+13}{2(x-3)}\right)^2-4\\
&=&\frac{(x^2-6x+13)^2 - 16(x-3)^2}{4(x-3)^2}\\
&=&\frac{169-156 x+62 x^2-12 x^3+x^4 - 16x^2+96x-144}{4(x-3)^2}\\
&=&\frac{x^4 -12x^3+46x^2 -60x+25}{4(x-3)^2}\\
&=&\frac{(x^2 -6x+5)^2}{4(x-3)^2}\\
&=&\frac{(x-5)^2(x-1)^2}{4(x-3)^2}\ge 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So only squares show up, hence it's positive.

Comment: I've changed $-13$ to $+13$ in two spaces (probably a typo). BTW the same can be done with less intermediate steps as
$(x^2-6x+13)^2-(4x-12)^2=(x^2-10x+25)(x^2-2x+1)=(x-5)^2(x-1)^2$; which is obtained using the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ for
$a=x^2-6x+13$ and $b=4x-12$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks

Answer (score 2):

Expression in (2) is 
$$
2ab+\frac{1}{2ab}+\frac{5}{2}
$$
Applying $AM \geq GM$ on the first two terms gives
$$
2ab+\frac{1}{2ab} \geq 2
$$
Substituting in the previous expression yields the given inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Only the first problem.

By [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) you have
$$y=\frac{x+7}2+\frac2{x-3}$$
and thus
$$y-5=\frac{x-3}2+\frac2{x-3}.$$

So if you substitute $t=\frac{x-3}2$, it suffices to show
$$\left|t+\frac1t\right|\ge2$$
for $t\ne 0$, which is the same as
$$t+\frac1t\ge2$$
for $t>0$.

There are many methods how to show this last inequality.